# rand() gives still the same value

Tags: c++, random

I noticed that while practicing by doing a simple console-based quiz app. When I'm using `rand()` it gives me the same value several times in a row. The smaller number range, the bigger the problem is.

For example

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    x = rand() % 20 + 1;
    cout << x << ", ";
}
```

Will give me `1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14,` - there are definetely too much ones, right? I usually got from none to 4 odd numbers (rest is just the same, it can also be `11, 11, 11, 4, 11 ...`)

Am I doing something wrong? Or `rand()` is not so random that I thought it is?
(Or is it just some habit from C#/Java that I'm not aware of? It happens a lot to me, too...)

Comment: `something % 1` always gives 0. Was it `rand() % 20 + 1`?

Comment: You need to seed your random. Look into `srand`. People frequently use `time()` as a seed (although this is not necessarily good practice).

Comment: @RageD: And you need to call `srand()` exactly *once* before any calls to `rand()`.

Comment: try this before `for` loop: `srand(time(NULL));`

Comment: The code in your question will not produce the output in your question; it will give `20, 20, 20, 20, ...`. Please copy-and-paste the code and the output from the same program. (Perhaps you meant `rand() % 20 + 1`?)

Comment: @DanielFischer - yes, it is `20 + 1`, fixed it (the function was too big to copypaste it so I mistyped the code)

Comment: That's too small a sample to draw any conclusions from. Run it 100 times and see what happens. Still small, but bigger than what you have now.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I ran it a million times, just to see what happened =)

Comment: Adding seed to the rand didn't help, sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I run that code a couple of times, I get different output. Sure, not as varied as I'd like, but seemingly not deterministic (although of course it is, since `rand()` only gives pseudo-random numbers...).

However, the way you treat your numbers isn't going to give you a uniform distribution over [1,20], which I guess is what you expect. To achieve that is rather more complicated, but in no way impossible. For an example, take a look at the [documentation for `<random>` at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/) - at the bottom there's a showcase program that generates a uniform distribution over [0,1). To get that to [1,20), you simply change the input parameters to the generator - it can give you a uniform distribution over any range you like.

I did a quick test, and called `rand()` one million times. As you can see in the output below, even at very large sample sizes, there are some nonuniformities in the distribution. As the number of samples goes to infinity, the line will (probably) flatten out, using something like `rand() % 20 + 1` gives you a distribution that takes *very* long time to do so. If you take something else (like the example above) your chances are better at achieving a uniform distribution even for quite small sample sizes.

[image: 1 million calls to rand()]

**Edit:**
I see several others posting about using `srand()` to seed the random number generator before using it. This is good advice, but it won't solve your problem in this case. I repeat: **seeding is not the problem in this case.**

Seeds are mainly used to control the reproducibility of the output of your program. If you seed your random number with a constant value (e.g. 0), the program will give the same output every time, which is useful for testing that everything works the way it should. By seeding with something non-constant (the current time is a popular choice)  you ensure that the results vary between different runs of the program.

Not calling `srand()` at all is the same as calling `srand(1)`, by the C++ standard. Thus, you'll get the same results every time you run the program, but you'll have a perfectly valid series of pseudo-random numbers within each run.

Comment: I note that while the scaling approach is a lot better than `rand() % 20`, it's still slightly non-uniform because the number of values that multiply up to each is going to be slightly different. To see why consider the case where you are multiple up to a range similar in size to the number of bits in the mantissa of your [0,1) ranged representation.

Comment: @JackAidley: Sure - but the scaling approach is usually "good enough" (i.e. it's really only scientific computations, or algorithms that heavily depend on the numbers being as random as possible that can't make do with it). However, you could just as well use the uniform distribution I linked to without scaling - and then it'd actually be uniform =). I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: One of the major purposes of `srand` is to allow you to be able to replicate results for troubleshooting unexpected results, which is the point of this particular question.  The SO saw an unexpected pattern.

Comment: @TomasLycken - I was doing the same thing, but running the loop 10kk times and the chart generated using output of my code was far away from being a straight line. I have done this loop for combination between using modulo, rand() parameters, different seeds, running it 10, 1k times, etc... Over 4GB of output data was processed (now let someone show me anyone who thinks that SSD is just a fancy gadget). I may elaborate the results more and then post them on demand, but there are two lessons learned: rand() is not so random than I thought, and if something seems easy - it's definetely not.

Comment: @PabloLemurr: No, as stated elsewhere in this Q/A-thread, `rand()` is not a good choice if you need high-quality randomness =) I'm no expert on pseudo-random number generators (trying to learn as much as I can, though) but [the random C++ library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random) does seem to have a lot of good choices - and it gives enough to start with for further investigations. And oh, Google Scholar is also your friend =)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're hitting *modulo bias*.

Scaling your random numbers to a range by using `%` is not a good idea. It's just about passable if your reducing it to a range that is a power of 2, but still pretty poor. It is primarily influenced by the smaller bits which are frequently less random with many algorithms (and `rand()` in particular), and it contracts to the smaller range in a non-uniform fashion because the range your reducing to will not equally divide the range of your random number generator. To reduce the range you should be using a division and loop, like so:

```
// generate a number from 0 to range-1
int divisor = MAX_RAND/(range+1);
int result;
do
{
    result = rand()/divisor;
} while (result >= range);
```

This is not as inefficient as it looks because the loop is nearly always passed through only once. Also if you're ever going to use your generator for numbers that approach `MAX_RAND` you'll need a more complex equation for `divisor` which I can't remember off-hand.

Also, `rand()` is a very poor random number generator, consider using something like a Mersenne Twister if you care about the quality of your results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `srand()` first and give it the time for parameter for better pseudorandom values.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int x,i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        x = rand() % 20 + 1;
        cout << x << ", ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want any of the generated numbers to repeat and memory isn't a concern you can use a `vector` of ints, shuffle it randomly and then get the values of the first N ints.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Get 5 random numbers between 1 and 20
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=1; i<=20; i++)
        v.push_back(i);
    random_shuffle(v.begin(),v.end());
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, seeding is irrelevant here. Not calling `srand()` at all is equivalent to calling `srand(1)`, which will give the same output between different runs, but it will be no less random *within the same run* of the program than seeding with any other number.

Comment: Well, it will give the same values every run so that`s why I suggested using time for seeding.

Comment: Sure - but that's not the problem the OP is talking about :P The question is about why the *same pseudo-random number series* has so low variation. Seeding has nothing to do with that.

Comment: You are right, I`ve made an edit. I hope this answers the OP's question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The likely problems are that you are using the same "random" numbers each time and that any `int` mod 1 is zero.  In other words `(myInt % 1 == 0`) is always true.  Instead of `%1`, use `% theBiggestNumberDesired`.

Also, seed your random numbers with `srand`.  Use a constant seed to verify that you are getting good results.  Then change the seed to make sure you are still getting good results.  Then use a more random seed like the clock to teat further.  Release with the random seed.

Comment: Actually, seeding is irrelevant here. Not calling `srand()` at all is equivalent to calling `srand(1)`, which will give the same output between different runs, but it will be no less random *within the same run* of the program than seeding with any other number.

Comment: Actually, seeding is relevant. The SO noticed an unexpected pattern when the default seed was used.  Using a different seed allows you to check if any patterns that you are seeing are by random chance or actually due to a systemic bias.

Comment: Well, seeding might be relevant as a means of troubleshooting, but it does not explain the pattern, and it does not "make sure that you are getting good results" - the results will be just as good (or bad) without calling `srand()`, but it might be easier to *find out why they're bad* if you do...

Comment: It helps you verify your results.